# Passa variável externa ou Constante para dentro de uma Função

Tags: php

Como passar uma variável para dentro de uma função estando essa variável no lado de fora. Não sei o que mais posso fazer      .

```
 <?php
 $id_transfer = $_SESSION["id_transfer"];
 $ptv = $_GET["tipo"];

 /////// Função Pegar o Fornecedor////////////// 
 function get_marcas() {
 $idt = IDT;
 $uf2 = UF;  
 $sql = "select * from fornecedores where id_transfer = $idt  AND uf =   
 '$uf2'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

 $marcas = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $marcas[] = $row;
 }
 return $marcas;
 }


 /////// Função Pegar o Veiculo////////////// 
 function get_modelos($id_marca,$ptv) {
 if(!ctype_digit($id_marca)) return array();


 $sql = sprintf("select * from veiculos where tipo = '$ptv' AND   
 id_fornecedor = %d",   
 $id_marca);
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($conexao));

  $modelos = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $modelos[] = $row;
  }
  return $modelos;
  }

  switch ($_POST['acao']) {
  case "exibeModeloSelect":
    $txt =  '<select name="id_veiculo" class="form-control">';
    $txt .= '<option value="">Selecione o Veiculo</option>';

    foreach(get_modelos($_POST['id_marca'],$ptv) as $modelo) {
        $txt .= '<option value="'.$modelo['id_veiculo'].'">' .  
    $modelo['modelo'] . '&nbsp; Placa:&nbsp;' . $modelo['placa'] .  
    '</option>';    
    }

    $txt .= "</select>";

    echo $txt;
    break;
    }


       /////// Função Pegar o Motorista////////////// 

   function get_cor($id_marca) {

   if(!ctype_digit($id_marca)) return array();        

   $id_marca = mysql_real_escape_string($id_marca);
   $sql = sprintf("select * from motoristas where id_fornecedor = %d",  
   $id_marca);
   $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

   $modelos = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $cor[] = $row;
   }
   return $cor;
   }





   switch ($_POST['acao']) {
   case "exibeModeloSelect": 
    $txt2 =  '<br><select name="id_motorista" class="form-control">';
    $txt2 .= '<option value="">Selecione o Motorista</option>';

    foreach(get_cor($_POST['id_marca']) as $cor) {
        $txt2 .= '<option value="'.$cor['id'].'">' . $cor['nomecompleto'] .   
   '&nbsp; Telefone:&nbsp; ' . $cor['tel'] . '</option>';   
    }

    $txt2 .= "</select>";

    echo $txt2;
    break;
    }  
    ?>
```

Comment: Há várias formas de introduzir o valor dessa variável no escopo da função, como podes ver nas respostas abaixo, exemplificam várias formas de o fazer. Para que seja mais claro e objetivo, podes dizer de onde provém o valor dessa variável ? Ou de onde queres que ela venha ?

Comment: Essa variável vem de uma outra consulta que me lista o tipo de veiculo

Comment: Okay, é possível editares a pergunta e adicionares também essa outra parte ?

Comment: coloquei o codigo completo mais não coloquei  a consulta pois ficaria muito grande o codigo aqui, mais coloquei la em cima uma essa variavel como se estivesse vindo de um $_GET que daria no mesmo

Comment: Eu só queria que o where tipo = '$ptv   pega-se essa variavel #$ptv

Comment: Olha, comenta o resto do código, e faça: `print($ptv)` ou `echo $ptv`. E diga o que retornou.

Comment: Esta retornando  Van

Comment: Obs na primeira função "function get_marcas() { "   eu consigo colocar variaveis la dentro vindo de constantes mais na segunda nem as constante funcionam.

Comment: Já experimentaste retornar o valor de `$_POST['id_marca']` ? Olha, se possível, coloca o código todo no _pastebin_ juntamente com as tabelas em uso.

Answer (score 1):

Mude a assinatura da função adicionando o novo parâmetro e se quiser defina um valor padrão.

```
function get_modelos($id_marca, $ptv=10) {
```

Depois basta chamar:

```
get_modelos($id_marca, 'van');
```

Answer (score 0):

segundo a documentação neste [link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php), existem algumas formas de se fazer

```
<?php

  $a = 1; /* escopo global */

  function Teste()
  {
    echo $a; /* referencia uma variável do escopo local (não definida) */
  }

  Teste();
?>
```

ou ainda utilizando as váriaveis globais

```
<?php
  $a = 1;
  $b = 2;

  function Soma()
  {
      global $a, $b;

      $b = $a + $b;
  }

  Soma();
  echo $b;
?>
```

mas acho que é a mais sensata é passar a variável como parâmetro da função

```
<?php
  $ptv = 'Van';//   Essa é a variavel que entrar no Where do select

  function get_modelos($id_marca,$ptv) {

    if(!ctype_digit($id_marca)) return array();
    $sql = sprintf("select * from veiculos where tipo = '$ptv' AND    
    id_fornecedor = %d", $id_marca);
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($conexao));

    $modelos = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $modelos[] = $row;
    }
    return $modelos;
  }
?>
```

Todos estes exemplos estão no link acima...

Comment: Testei neste ultimo exemplo e deu este erro... Warning: Missing argument 2 for get_modelos(), called in

Comment: Quando vc chamouba função vc passou o segundo parâmetro? `get_modelos($id_marca,$ptv)` mas lembre-se de iniciar a variável e ter certeza que ela é válida...